# Invalid direct reference to form login page while going to scrape a page using PHP cURL

Tags: php, curl, web-scraping, j-security-check

I am doing **scraping** of page using `PHP cURL`. I have to login to the website by passing credentials to login form action. Here is the cases I'm getting.:

**Case #1:**

When accessing page using browser, this is the form which is being submitted to the server.

```
<form id="formLogin" name="formLogin" method="post" action="../public/j_security_check"> 
    <input type="hidden" id="j_token" name="j_token" value="0">
    <input type="hidden" id="j_username" name="j_username" value="">
    <input type="text" id="username_txt" name="username_txt" size="20" onChange="HidePageMessage()" onkeydown='onAutoSubmit(event)'>
    <input type="password" id="j_password" name="j_password" size="20" onChange="HidePageMessage()" onkeydown='onAutoSubmit(event)'  onkeypress="capsDetect(event)">
    <select id="carrierCode" name="carrierCode" STYLE="width: 120px">
        <option value="val1">Some Option</option>
        <option value="val2">Some Option</option>
        <option value="val3">Some Option</option>
        <option value="valn">Some Option</option>
    </select>
    <input type="button" id="btnClose" value="Close" class="loginButton" onclick="window.close()" i18n_key="close">
    <input type="button" id="btnLogin" value="Login" class="loginButton" onclick="login()" i18n_key="login">
    <input type="hidden" id="hdnUserStatus" name="hdnUserStatus" value="" />
</form>
```

When I submit button with correct credentials, it sends data to the following url with these information:

**General**

```
Request URL:https://example.com/agents/public/j_security_check
Request Method:POST
Status Code:302 Moved Temporarily
Remote Address:86.96.201.171:443
```

**Response Headers**

```
Content-Length:0
Date:Wed, 08 Mar 2017 04:16:15 GMT
Location:http://example.com/agents/private/showXBEMain.action
Set-Cookie:aeroID=16395617314887938521488793852650522;expires=Tue, 02-Jan-2018 04:16:15 GMT;path=/;
```

**Request Headers**

```
Accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language:en-GB,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.6
Cache-Control:max-age=0
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:136
Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Cookie:JSESSIONID=F16F95247A3E529FA526B5FBD6C9CE87.aapuga64; aeroID=16395617314887938521488793852650522
Host:domain.com
Origin:https://example.com
Referer:https://example.com/agents/private/showXBEMain.action
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests:1
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/56.0.2924.87 Safari/537.36
```

Form Data

```
j_token:1
j_username: some_credential
username_txt: loginid
j_password: password
carrierCode: somecode
hdnUserStatus:
```

As a success result, it's redirected to another page which is correct, but when going to access this page using `PHP cURL`, it's giving ' **Invalid direct reference to form login page**' and status code: `400`

**case #2:**

When passing the same field with wrong credentials, it's giving status `200` and a message inside js code '`LOGINFAILED`' which is correct, and as expected.

**case #3:**

When passing the same failds with correct credentials, neither it's redirecting to another page as it should do, nor giving `LOGINFAILED` message. it's giving `400` status code, and message as '`Invalid direct reference to form login page`'

I searched a lot about this on the web, it's a type of `j_security_check` error of `java` and the solutions for that is inside the code of server. And in my case I'm doing **scraper** where I do not know what they have written inside the server.

Comment: record logging in with Chrome, use the "Network" tab of Developer Tools.  then recording logging in with curl.  now compare the 2 logins, and weed out every single difference between Chrome's login requests, and Curl's login requests (well, except the `Accept-Encoding`, because curl doesn't support sdch)

Comment: I did the same thing as you said before posting

Comment: then you got something wrong. what website? and do you have a test account you can share?  i could try